# SSRS IIF expression for Counting Division

Tags: reporting-services

Hi I am trying to write an expression of COunt Division based on price as shown in figure http://i43.tinypic.com/2r47hqx.png

I am doing group column on Division but how can I get exact no. of count in Count Division Column those having price in their division.

Can anybody suggest any 'expression' that I can use in that Count Division Coulmn.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say you have a column called `Division` that you are grouping on, add a summary column, i.e. outside of the column group, and set the textbox expression to:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Division.Value)
```

This will be applied in the row scope only so will effectively be a count of all non-null divisions in that row.

Comment: Awesome.. Believe me I tried some creepy long IIF conditions since last 2 days.. thanks alot!!! It worked...